# Nautilus (Files) show drives in launcher

Tags: mount, nautilus, launcher, 16.04

How to handle different HD (mounted in folders from the FSTAB) in the same Nautilus? for example, I have mounted my music hd in Music folder, when I click in Music folder another instance of Nautilus is open. And that with all the rest of HDs. Is posible disable that?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide `fstab` mounted drives from the Launcher, you can do it this way:

Install `dconf-editor` if you haven't already.

Start `dconf-editor` and scroll down to com → canonical → Unity → devices and enter the UUID of the mount in blacklist.

Here's an example of what it looks like on my system.

[image]

Comment: I did that and hide the units, but when I click on one of them it is out again, and start using a new nautilus window...may this excerpt from webupd8.com explain better:  " the file manager (Nautilus) is now integrated with Unity Launcher, so every device icon available on Unity Launcher only manages the relative window, while the Files (Nautilus) icon matches the other views. For instance, if you click on the Trash (or USB devices, etc.) icon, the Nautilus window that opens is managed from the Trash icon, and not from the Nautilus icon from the Launcher; "

Answer (score 0):

This is a duplicate of the following question, which includes a more robust answer (the given one is only useful for permanently attached storage):

[How to stop partition icons in Unity launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/811867/how-to-stop-partition-icons-in-unity-launcher)

Comment: This should be posted as a comment